# Using a string as function argument r with networks

Tags: r, string, graph, igraph, purrr

I’m trying write a function that apply *"a series of operations to multiple graphs"* in my workspace that I identify with a given suffix;

Let's say **name_g**, however I can’t make the function to properly recognize the string. I’ve tried solutions proposed in other posts but usually I get the error.

"*Error in .f(.x[[i]], ...) : Not a graph object* " when using substitute and eval

```
library(igraph)
library(igraphdata)
library(purrr)

data(karate)
data(kite)
data(immuno)

karate_g <- karate
kite_g <- kite
immuno_g <- immuno

foo <- function(x){
 all_networks <- mget(ls(pattern = x))

 all_networks %>%
    map(cluster_fast_greedy) %>% 
    map(sizes) %>% 
    map(max)
}

foo("_g")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to refer to the correct environment:

```
foo <- function(x){
    all_networks <- mget(ls(pattern = x, pos= 1L),  envir = as.environment(1L))

    all_networks %>%
       map(cluster_fast_greedy) %>% 
       map(sizes) %>% 
       map(max)
}

foo("_g")
# $immuno_g
# [1] 320

# $karate_g
# [1] 18

# $kite_g
# [1] 4
```